# Error receiving a HttpResponseMessage OK

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, httpresponse

I am with a problem. I have 2 WebApi´s . The webapi2 get the data from DB and return the IMAGE. Here, its ok and working. If i try on browser, show me the image or if i change, the byte array.
The problem is with the Webapi1 that calls this webapi2. I always receive the HttpResponseMessage with false for IsSuccessStatusCode. The error is 500 internal server error.
I am a newbie and i don´t know what to do...i already tryed a lot of things

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFoto(string exemplo, string exemple2)
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.111.56.1:1762/");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Tr/Test?exemplo="+exemplo+"&pk="+pk+"");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

                return response;
            }
            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
                return null;
            }


        }
    }
```

My webapi that Works and return me a Image:

```
  //connections code that doesn´t matter....

            try
            {

                HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(imgBytes);
                result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

                return result;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
            }
```

Comment: Have you checked in your system event logs and any application logs to understand what is causing the 500? It is likely that they API being called is throwing an exception. Make sure you are not just discarding exceptions with try {} catch {} and ensure you wrap the method in the API with a try catch that logs any exceptions to the file system to help troubleshoot. Good luck!

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft i edited the post ! So, yes, i am using the try catch. The problem is that the response for the webapi is OK and return the image... when the other webapi receive this, thats the problem. I don´t know where are theses logs.

Comment: Ah, so the other WebApi is not under your control? You will need to go to the supplier / owner and ask them to check their logs. A 500 is typically an unhandled error in the API. If your data was just incorrect or you were calling it improperly, it should (if built properly) just return something in the 400 ish range like a Bad Request. But a 500 is near terminal, something crashed on their side.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft no no, is under my control ! What i am telling you is that the webapi is not with error !! If i call this webapi(2) on the browser, i got the image... but if a call a webapi(1) that call this webapi(2), i don´t get. The IsSuccessStatusCode is false and i get the error 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because when you pass a value on the browser, they change some carachters... So, you are passing 2 values... you have to use

On the webapi 1

```
var MIRACLE =  Uri.EscapeDataString(exemplo);
```

And at the webapi2

```
var MIRACLE2 = Uri.UnescapeDataString(MIRACLE)
```

Comment: yessss. Thats it... thats why when i tried just the webapi 2, was working... The problem is when the webapi handle to the webapi2... some special characters changes and i was receiving FALSE to IsSuccessStatusCode ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, the web api 1 will accept only the media type = "application/json".
This is because you have added the below code :

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

So either you remove the line of code or change it to "image/jpeg" from "application/json".